# Combining "most" and "second most"

Tags: adverbs, past-participles

I want to write the following sentence. But it sounds a bit weird for me as a non-native speaker.

> English was the most or second most used language in 100 groups.

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant "English was the most OR second most used language". I updated the question. Your interpretation is correct. But is it correct?

Comment: You might want to hyphenate second-most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the second article:

- English was the most or the second-most used language in 100 groups.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not agree that the second article and hyphen are needed. "In each UK nation ophthalmology is either the first or second most common reason for attending an outpatient appointment." "Cervical cancer is the first or second most common cancer and a leading cause of cancer deaths among women in low-and middle-income countries" "More than half rank the economy as the first or second most important issue that will impact their vote. "